# To do chained payments 'must get permission from PayPal' - what does that mean?

Tags: paypal, chained-payments

I am trying to find a method to implement chained payments, but where I am the secondary receiver, and am making the API call on behalf of another PayPal account, who would be the primary receiver. Is it possible to make this API call on behalf of another person? The other person would likely has a Verified Premiere account (rather than a Business Verified account).

One reason I am unsure that this is possible is because the documentation on chained payments clearly states 'The API caller must get permission from PayPal to use chained payments.' (via https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/), but it doesn't make it clear what that means. Does anyone know what the requirements are? Would both I and the primary receiver need this 'permission'? How does one go about getting this permission?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[When you create an APP-ID in the developer.paypal.com center](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/lifecycle/goingLive/) (see under *Reviewing applications with Adaptive API calls*) you set up which features your applications will use. Some features are considered "basic" and do not require any special permissions adn your app will have a status of "**Approved Automatically**" if your app needs some special features (such is chained payments) your app will have to got through review process and the status will be "**Conditionally Approved**"  What this means you can use basic features (such as simple adaptive payments) but you cannot use special features, until it is approved. Furthermore when you create an APP ID you have to specify that you will use this feature (granting permissions to third party user) so that APP is enabled to use this feature

**Edit:** Worth to note that when create the sandbox account your application will have all features enabled and it wil not require any special permissions from Paypal, so don't be fooled by that; because once you go live it will throw an error if your APP-ID is not approved (or rather if it is conditionally approved). Review process can take weeks, so I will advise to plan in advance and not take assumptions that if it works in sandbox environment that it will work in live by default.

Comment: So if I am understanding this correctly, the 'permission' is associated with the App ID and not the PayPal user, therefore I should be able to insert a third party as the primary receiver in a chained payment without too much hassle.

Comment: This is assuming that the PayPal Permissions Service can grant permission to do chained payments, but I suppose that is another question.

Comment: @Aurora  Yes and Yes  generally if it is simple chain payment `your app->primary receiver -> secondary receivers` it shouldn't take that long. I don't know what are the reason behind this permission approval, but as far as API implementation goes chain payments are not much different than basic adaptive payment(there si just a third party).If you however are just sending transaction form one receiver to another(buyer->seller), you don't need chain payments. [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16827341/paypal-adaptive-payments-error-550001-you-do-not-have-permission-to-constrain)