# PayPal Adaptive Chained Payments in the sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, chained-payments

Chained payments in PayPal Adaptive Payments is documented as only being available with approval: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/

Is it possible to use it in the Sandbox without approval to test workflow and code, before submitting an application for approval?

Comment: This answer indicates this is possible:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/16903793/19079

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can try the API on sandbox without app approval. Just create a sandbox account from developer.paypal.com and use the account's API credentials along withe the special sandbox app id APP-80W284485P519543T.

When you go live, you will have to go through the app approval process to get your own app id